# Serializing XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, serialization, xna-4.0

> Type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.RasterizerState'
>   in Assembly
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Im trying to serialize sections of the xna game studio.

Unfortunately i can't directly serialize this class.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to serialize a `RasterizerState` as XML?

Comment: not to xml. the architecture im developing the game should consist of multiple graphics device options where the rasterizer state option is part of. for instance, when im dealing with 3 teams - each would have a set of graphics device options pertaining to the art they are performing. a person in team 1 decides that the graphics looks differently in team 2 or in team1 itself. at the end fo the day i need to run comparisons in what settings would eventuallywork . and therefore need to keep track of what goes with what. all the serialization gets done as binary.

Comment: Might I suggest a different serializer. XNA's `IntermediateSerializer` is perhaps suitable (downside: you can only serialize on Windows). It can handle arbitrary objects, and you can load its serialized output via the Content Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Its a common problem. The first question i would ask myself is why your trying to serialize an object which type is not marked as serializable. Did the author of that type leave it off for a reason? Is there a chance that in the future, the type will be expanded with some unserializable behavior?

Then there are 3 solutions in my head. Unfortunatly, you cant directly serialize the object. What you can do is this:

1. Create a wrapper object (marked as serializable) containing all the properties you want to serialize and copy the values from the actual object to the wrapper object and back.
2. Extending on option 1: Instread of a simple wrapper object, create a more dynamic wrapper class containing a list of KeyValuePairs where you bind the propertyNames to propertyValues and make some generic code which can fill this list based on a existing object and fill an object based on such a list.
3. Use unsafe code and do the serialization yourself (pin the object, read its memory and write to a memory stream). << This method is really really unsafe